# Feeding Data into ListView from SQLite Database

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, sqlite, listview

I have millions of records that need can be searched and then appear in a ListView. Currently, these items are stored in an SQLite internal database.

Does anyone have a recommendation on the best method to feed these items into a ListView and have people scroll through them? Speed is critical here.

I don't want to do a "SELECT *" off of the database and feed all of the items into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this great article about data virtualization in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDataVirtualization.aspx) on Code Project. It provides asynchronous virtualized collection classes that seem to fit your needs perfectly.

Comment: The guy who wrote that article is awesome. Thanks for the link!